# How to set enviroment variable Heroku

Tags: heroku

I need to set enviroment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS at .json format like service-account-file.json but i cant.
I tried this https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/buyersight/heroku-google-application-credentials-buildpack and this https://github.com/gerywahyunugraha/heroku-google-application-credentials-buildpack but it is not working.Heroku => java.io.IOException: Error reading credential file from environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, value 'google-credentials.json': File does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such ways to set environment variable from json file you can use the environment variable like process.env.VARIABLENAME and define that variable name in config

Here i attach the screenshots from where you can define the variable
[image]

Comment: My key is GOOGLE_APPLICATON_CREDENTIALS, my value is MUST BE .json format service-account-file.json but i dont know how can i set value as a .json file.

Comment: Heroku does not allowed to set the value in json format.